# How to register correctly a DatePickerInput component from Mantine in react-hook-form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form, mantine

I am working in registering the inputs from a big form into the useForm() hook from react-hook-form library. Now I am trying to register a DatePickerInput which is a component from mantine. I am trying this approach using Controller:

```
export const DayPickerComponent: FC<DayPickerProps>=({title}) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
    const [value, setValue] = useState<Date|null>(null)
  

    return (
      <div className='w-full lg:w-1/2 '>
        <h1 className='text-lg mt-5 font-bold ml-2 mr-2 flex'>{title}</h1>
        <div className='ml-2 mr-2'>
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name={title}
          render={({field})=>(
            <DatePickerInput
            icon={<IconCalendar size="1.1rem" stroke={1.5} />}
            placeholder="Pick date"
            value={value}
            onChange={setValue}
            mx="auto"
          />
          )}
        />
        </div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The controller seems to register the component, but when the values are printed after onSubmit, the DatePickerInput value is undefined even though as you will see in the image, the field has a value.

[DatePickerInput assigned to undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRKe0.png)

I am expecting to register correctly the component into the useForm hook with its value included.